# How to implement a endless ViewPager?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, tabview

**My app**
My App shows a ListView with CheckBoxes in each row. The CheckBoxes are saved for each day. Buttons are used to navigate between the different days.

**The Problem**
I want a slideable TabView instead. I tried to use ViewPager, but I don´t know how to implement it the right way. The problem is that I need tabs for the days between year 2000 and now. How can I achieve this?

**This is how the app should look like**
[image: This is how my app should look like]

Comment: Your question is really broad, but I'm thinking this would best be implemented using a RecyclerView for your tabs. It would be a lot less resource intensive than a ViewPager since all you would have to do is update your CheckBox items based on the item selected in your RecylerView and not reloading your view by "paging" to it.

Comment: But how can I get a slide animation without viewpager?